# Angular-CLI: spurious GETs for files from other project?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli, browser-sync

This is driving me crazy, and I can't find any explanation.

I am running a project built with ng-cli 1.4.2 on node 6.11.2 on OSX.

We start it by firing up a node server with npm in a server directory, then switch to a client directory and run

`ng serve --sourcemap --extractCss -o --hmr -e=hmr --proxy-config proxy.config.json`

where proxy.config.json is

```
{
"/":{
  "target": "http://localhost:8081",
  "secure": false,
  "logLevel": "debug",
  "changeOrigin": true
 }
}
```

We do this so we can use our authentication for the site.

It works fine, except that I get a series of GETs in the Terminal for files that are *not part of this project at all*, but are part of another project which we sometimes run on the same port with Gulp with Browsersync.

The Gulp project is *not* running at the time.  I have killed all node processes first, quit terminal, even rebooted the computer.  But then running the app requests these files:

`[HPM] GET /assets/images/icon-article.svg -> http://localhost:8081`

For example.  That file *does* exist in the older project.

How is this happening?

Comment: Any chance you have a browser window open that's trying to hit the Gulp project?

Comment: Nope, I quit the browser before running.